# Passing the usercontrol as a parameter to a resource in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, parameters

I have what should be a relatively simple question, but I can't find the answer anywhere. I'm declaring a converter in the resources section of my UserControl in xaml. That converter has a property I've set up where I want to pass in "this", that is, the UserControl called EventTagger. In a binding you can normally user ElementName="EventTagger" to access properties at least of the main UserControl, but I can't figure out how to do this as a property to a converter, because I can't use a binding here. I'd also be content passing the DataContext here, but can't figure out how to pass that either. Thoughts?

```
<UserControl Name="EventTagger" ...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <TagFrameVerificationConverter x:Key="tagFrameVerificationConverter Tagger="?"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
     ...
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Can you use the converter parameter?

Comment: I don't believe so, since I don't think you can use bindings in converter parameters either.

Comment: No you're correct, because the converter paramter is a part of a binding itself.  So do you just need to set a property on your converter? I guess your XAML above is not really clear to me what you're trying to do.

Comment: I need my converter to have a pointer to the instance of the UserControl I'm defining, or, if that is impossible, at least the DataContext of the control. I don't really care how, I thought the easiest way would be with a property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The converter won't have any `DataContext` so even if your `IValueConverter` derives from `DependencyObject` and Tagger is a `DependencyProperty` you won't be able to bind it using `DataContext`, `RelativeSource` or `ElementName`. Only `Source` will work (which isn't much good in your case).

You can use [`x:Reference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380.aspx) instead

```
<UserControl Name="EventTagger" ...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <TagFrameVerificationConverter x:Key="tagFrameVerificationConverter"
                                       Tagger="{x:Reference EventTagger}"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

If you're using the VS2010 designer you'll get an error saying

> Service provider is missing the INameResolver service

This is just a designer bug and it can be worked around as described here on connect:
[Visual Studio 2010 InvalidOperationException using x:Reference in WPF](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/660141/visual-studio-2010-invalidoperationexception-using-x-reference-in-wpf).
In `ProvideValue` we return `null` if we're in design mode.

```
[ContentProperty("Name")]
public class Reference : System.Windows.Markup.Reference
{
    private static DependencyObject _dependencyObject = new DependencyObject();
    public Reference()
        : base()
    { }

    public Reference(string name)
        : base(name)
    { }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(_dependencyObject) == true)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return base.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! This works like a charm. Never heard of the x:Reference tag before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So based on the comments, would something like this work:

```
<UserControl Name="EventTagger" ...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <TagFrameVerificationConverter x:Key="tagFrameVerificationConverter" Tagger="{Binding}"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
     ...
</UserControl>
```

Your `Tagger` property should be a `DependencyProperty` so it can handle the bindings properly, and then the `"{Binding}"` just means "bind to the current data context".

The more general answer to your question is that you can have public properties on your converter, and you can set those properties in XAML as I have in my sample above.

Comment: I don't believe this will work, since a Converter is not a DependencyObject, and so you can't have DependencyProperties on it.

Comment: You can make it a `DependencyObject` if you want, you just inherit from `DependencyObject`.